# How can I suppress output when running a Laravel artisan command? Is there a --quiet option?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I have an artisan command that's run from cron:

```
php artisan telescope:prune
```

This command (like many artisan commands) produces output. That's fine for interactive use, but when I run commands like this from cron, I prefer to follow the cron convention and not produce any output unless there's an error.

Many commands support a `--quiet` option, or require messy `>/dev/null` redirection to keep the noise down. I've looked in [the Laravel artisan docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/artisan#writing-output), but I can't see a way to control the output of such commands. When calling an artisan command from inside Laravel, it's possible to [suppress output by calling it with the `callSilently()` method](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/artisan#calling-commands-from-other-commands), but that's not available on the command line, as far as I can see.

How can I suppress output from artisan commands on the command line?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this is possible, it's just not documented.

Artisan commands implement an [InteractsWithIO](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/10.x/src/Illuminate/Console/Concerns/InteractsWithIO.php#L53) interface that defines output verbosity controls as command line options for *every* artisan command. The options are:

- `v`: Verbose
- `vv`: Very verbose
- `vvv`: Debug
- `quiet`: Quiet
- `normal`: Normal

Artisan commands can generate output through various channels (such as `info`, `line`, `comment`, `question`, `error`, see the interface class for details) which act much like log levels, allowing them to be filtered according to the verbosity options.

So, to answer my question directly, it's possible to suppress the output of this command by appending the `--quiet` option:

```
php artisan telescope:prune --quiet
```